# Combining matlab Scripts

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a user interactive animation in MATLAB where a shape translates and rotates across the screen and the user has to click on it and as soon as they click on white space, the program exits.  I have the animation and the clicking script written but I am unsure how to combine them.  I have posted each script below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
clear all; close all; clc
nSides =4;
%Polar points
r=1;
theta = pi/nSides * (1:2:2*nSides-1);

%Cartesisn points
x0 = r * cos(theta);
y0 = r * sin(theta);
nFrames = 100;
xx = linspace(0,10, nFrames);
yy = xx;

rr = linspace(0, 2*pi, nFrames);

for i = 1:nFrames

rX = [cos(rr(i)), -sin(rr(i))];
rY = [sin(rr(i)), cos(rr(i))];

x1 = rX * [x0; y0];
y1 = rY * [x0; y0];

y=fill(x1 + xx(i), y1 + yy(i), 'b');
xlim([0,10]); ylim([0,10]);
hold on;
pause(0.000000003);
delete(y);

end



xv = [ -3 3 3 -3]; %// x coords of polygon vertices. Arbitrary number
yv = [-5 -5 7 7]; %// y coords of polygon vertices. Same number as for x
fill(xv,yv,'b') %// draw polygon
axis([-10 10 -10 10])
[xp, yp] = ginput(1); %// get point coordinates
inside = inpolygon(xp,yp,xv,yv); %// is it inside?

while inside
fprintf('Inside\n')
[xp, yp] = ginput(1);
inside = inpolygon(xp,yp,xv,yv);
end
fprintf('Outside\n')
```

Errors:

```
Error using inpolygon (line 66)
Polygon must be defined by vectors (XV, YV).

Error in mouseDownCallback (line 20)
    if
    inpolygon(coordinates(1),coordinates(2),xVertices,yVertices) 
Error using pause
Error while evaluating figure WindowButtonDownFcn

Error using inpolygon (line 66)
Polygon must be defined by vectors (XV, YV).

Error in mouseDownCallback (line 20)
    if
    inpolygon(coordinates(1),coordinates(2),xVertices,yVertices) 
Error using pause
Error while evaluating figure WindowButtonDownFcn

Error using delete
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in movingPolygon (line 40)
delete(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to combining scripts is to register a callback with the figure that is displaying the polygon so that the callback fires every time the user clicks within the axes of the figure.  It is relatively straightforward and requires very few lines of code, though does make use of global variables which may or may not be an issue.  (The alternative to this is to create a class to manage the figure and callbacks, and removes the need for global variables.)

To make things a little simpler, change your first script into a function, which wraps the code as

```
function movingPolygon
    % your code
end
```

The function name can be the same as the script name.  We do this so that we can add the callback function to this file.  In your main function, declare three global variables after the clear commands

```
clear all; close all; clc

global gUserHitPolygon;   % indicates whether the user has hit the polygon or not
global gCurrentXVertices; % the x-vertices of the moving polygon
global gCurrentYVertices; % the y-vertices of the moving polygon
```

Default `gUserHitPolygon` to true since we want the polygon to move until the user hits the whitespace

```
gUserHitPolygon = true;
```

In the `for` loop to update the polygon position, just save the x- and y-vertices (used in `fill`) to the remaining two global variables.  So on each iteration of `i`, these two global variables are updated.

Now we continue moving the polygon until the user misses hit, so the last statement in your `for` loop, just after the pause, should be to check to see if the user has hit the polygon or missed it

```
if ~gUserHitPolygon
    clear GLOBAL gUserHitPolygon gCurrentXVertices gCurrentYVertices;
    break;
end
```

In the above, we just clear the global variables (since no longer needed) and break out of the `for` loop.

The only thing left to do, besides defining the callback, is to register for the mouse button down events.  Just prior to entering the `for` loop, create a figure and register it for this event

```
h = figure;
set(h,'WindowButtonDownFcn',   @mouseDownCallback);
```

That's it - the figure will now respond to mouse button down events.  The callback, defined in the same file, resembles your second script

```
% Callback for the mouse button down event.
function mouseDownCallback(~,~)

    global gUserHitPolygon;
    global gCurrentXVertices;
    global gCurrentYVertices;

    % save to local variables in case these globals are cleared (this is the
    % "danger" of using globals - not "thread-safe")
    xVertices = gCurrentXVertices;
    yVertices = gCurrentYVertices;

    % if we have valid (so non-empty) sets of x- and y-vertices then...
    if ~isempty(xVertices) && ~isempty(yVertices)

        % get the coordinate on the current axis
        coord = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
        coord = coord(1,1:2);

        % if the coordinate is not in the polygon, then change the
        % flag
        if ~inpolygon(coord(1),coord(2),xVertices,yVertices)
           gUserHitPolygon = false;
        end
    end
end
```

And that is it.  Try the above and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works but I want the animation to repeat until the user clicks outside the polygon.  So, if they click inside the polygon, the animation will repeat and a score variable will be updated. Would that be too much different from this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It wouldn't be much different.  Just use a global var that keeps track of the score and is incremented by one whenever the user hits inside the polygon (add an `else` statement to `if` in callback).  Then in the `movingPolygon` function,  use  `while gUserHitPolygon` loop conditioned on the `gUserHitPolygon` variable (you could then remove the `if` with `break` check as it would be unnecessary) rather than the `for` loop on number of frames.  Then just modify the code here to move the polygon - will it repeat the same pattern, bounce in the other direction, or ..??

Comment: It will repeat the same pattern.  I changed the for loop to a while loop but now the animation doesn't work because the rotation and the translation are dependent on the indices of the for loop.  How would I fix this?

Comment: Just prior to entering the `while` loop, initialize `i=1;` so that integer value can be used in the rotation and translation. Add the following as the last lines in your while loop: `i = i + 1;` and `if i>nFrames; i = 1; end;` (you won't need the semicolons at the end of the conditional and end, I just want to make clear that there are three lines to this if statement).  So on the next iteration of the `while` loop, `i` has been incremented by one and if ever we reach `nFrames`, then `i` gets reset to 1 (and so the polygon starts at the beginning).

Comment: I made those changes but for some reason it gives me the errors I outlined in the recent edit to the question.  How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Looking at the code you posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999990/user-interactive-animation-in-matlab, in the `mouseDownCallback`, when you declare the global variables, all three are missing the `g` prefix i.e. `CurrentXVertices` rather than `gCurrentXVertices`.  Please put suffix all with `g` and see if this helps.  (For sure there will be some unexpected behaviour if the variable is declared one way but then another named one is used instead.)

Comment: Thanks! it worked! But for some reason the score is not incrementing properly.  It counts the first click but does not go beyond there. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the line where the counter is incremented?  That way you can see if the code is being called properly.  If it isn't, i.e. the code doesn't pause at that line, look at the condition that is preventing it from doing so.